# Jquery selector for select options

Tags: jquery, html, select

I've got couple of "select" elements,
I need a true/false selector, whether one or any of them has a selected option with other than default which is "0" value.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not to use `filter`?

```
$("select").filter(function(index) {
    return $(this).val() != "0";
})
```

if you wish to use it in condition

```
if($("select").filter(function(index) {
    return $(this).val() != "0";
}).size() > 0) {
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Working like a charm! :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var is_all_zero = true;
$('select').each(function() {
  if ($(this).val() !== '0') {
    is_all_zero = false;
    return false;
  }
});
```

And replace the selector with yours.

Comment: Thanks for reply :) The other solution is the same, but looks a little more elegant.